# How to show record OrderID-Null-Null

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having this problem.
There are 2 table, the first one is like:

```
OrderID | OrderDetailID
1       | 1
1       | 2
```

The second is like:

```
OrderDetailID | Quantity | Quality | Description
NULL               NULL      NULL       NULL
```

The second table have no record
How to write a Oracle or sql show record like this:

```
OrderID | OrderDetailID | OrderDetailID | Quantity | Quality | Description
 1      | 1            | NULL          |     NULL |     NULL|      NULL
```

The point is I cannot use any Full outer join because it will trigger the "Cannot Select For Update From view with group by, distinct, etc..."

Comment: SQL Server or Oracle? What are you *really* using? Where does the error you partially quote come from? What was the attempt that generated that error?

Comment: There is a difference between "no rows" and a single row with `NULL` values.  Which actually represents the data?

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like you just want to add empty columns to the resultset of `table1`. If so, just:

```
select orderid, orderdetailsid, null as quantity, null as quality, null as description
from table1
```

Or maybe your intent is a `left join`:

```
select t1.orderid, t1.orderdetailsid, t2.quantity, t3.quality, t2.description
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.orderdetailsid = t1.orderdetailsid
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `OUTER JOIN` during creation of the view such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_t12 AS
SELECT t1.orderid, t1.orderdetailid AS orderdetailid1,
       t2.orderdetailid AS orderdetailid2, t2.quantity, t2.quality, t2.description
  FROM table2 t2
 RIGHT JOIN table1 t1
    ON t2.OrderDetailID = t1.OrderDetailID;
```

**or**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_t12 AS
SELECT t1.orderid, t1.orderdetailid AS orderdetailid1,
       t2.orderdetailid AS orderdetailid2, t2.quantity, t2.quality, t2.description
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.OrderDetailID = t1.OrderDetailID;
```

Then, you'll get `ORA-01445: Cannot Select ROWID from a Join View without a Key-Preserved Table` error whenever issue the query containing `FOR UPDATE` Clause such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM v_t12 t
   FOR UPDATE
```

then add **Primary Key** to the first table such as

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1
  ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ORD_ID_DET_ID PRIMARY KEY (ORDERDETAILID, ORDERID);
```

**and**

then add **Unique Key** to the second table such as

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE2
  ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ORD_DET_ID UNIQUE (ORDERDETAILID)
```

in order to avoid the error.